Descarga de archivo PDF en desde React JS con nombre por defecto
tengo este botón que sirve para descargar un archivo pdf. Funciona bien pero se descarga con un nombre por defecto (_static_media_nicolascragnocv2024.922a071055470c0903ca.pdf). Es posible asignarle un nombre? Este es el botón:
<Link to={Curriculum} target='_blank' download={Curriculum}>
 <button className='cv-page-btn'>DESCARGAR PDF</button>
</Link>

Muchas gracias!

Usa la propiedad download para renombrar.
<a href="/some-file" download="miarchivo.txt">
    descargar mediante &lt;a&gt;
  </a>

Puedes leer más acerca de este atributo en la especificación.
¿Qué tiene que ver?
Resulta que Link termina generando un anchor (a), por lo que muchas de sus propiedades son iguales, así que puedes hacer algo tipo
<Link to="/some-file" download="miarchivo.pdf" target="_blank">
    descargar mediante &lt;Link&gt;
</Link>

Esto lo puedes verificar con este sandbox.
